# How to show different Italic and Oblique styles when the font provides them?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, fonts

For example the [Victor Mono](https://rubjo.github.io/victor-mono/) font has vastly different (ie. properly designed) Italic and Oblique styles, and I'm using it as my prefered programming font, however I can't seem to make it properly show both styles at the same time in code editors/text processors or on a webpage.

When I installed the font on my local system, both Italic and Oblique shows the Italic variant, I figured it might be an issue with the OS font system, so I tried to embed the fonts with CSS like this

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Victor Mono';
    src: url('VictorMono-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Victor Mono';
    src: url('VictorMono-Italic.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Victor Mono';
    src: url('VictorMono-Oblique.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: oblique;
}
```

but now both

```
html {font-family:Victor Mono; font-weight:normal; font-style: italic;}
```

and

```
html {font-family:Victor Mono; font-weight:normal; font-style: oblique;}
```

shows the Oblique style. While if I re-order the @font-face rules to put the Italic one below the Oblique one like this

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Victor Mono';
    src: url('VictorMono-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Victor Mono';
    src: url('VictorMono-Oblique.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: oblique;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Victor Mono';
    src: url('VictorMono-Italic.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

both Italic and Oblique styles will show the Italic variant. So it seems font-style: italic and font-style: oblique are actually interpreted as the same rule by the render engine and the rule appears later will override the former one?

So how should I show different italic and oblique font styles? For example I'd like VSCode to show comments in Italic style while reserved keywords in Oblique style. Currently it shows Italic all the time for both comments and reserved keywords which hurts my eyes when I look through the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think its beacause of same font-family name, try this out:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Victor Mono Normal';
src: url('VictorMono-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;}
@font-face {
font-family: 'Victor Mono Oblique';
src: url('VictorMono-Oblique.ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: oblique;}
@font-face {
font-family: 'Victor Mono Italic';
src: url('VictorMono-Italic.ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: italic;}
```

Comment: oh well, I guess separating them into three different font families can do the trick, but that kinda defeats the purpose of the font-style rule? Does this mean the current implementation of the font-style rule has a serious bug so Italic and Oblique have to be treated as two different font families to work properly...

Comment: the fonts are called by its font-family name if u give the same name than its call the last one thats why we need to give different-different names.

Comment: errr, nope, the font-faces can have the same font-family name but different font-weight and font-style, thus VictorMono-Oblique.ttf and VictorMono-Italic.ttf would not override the VictorMono-Regular.ttf rule, and I can actually define same font-family name for different weights, like VictorMono-Light.ttf and VictorMono-Medium.ttf, and they will not interfere with each other, it seems only "font-style: italic" and "font-style: oblique" will interfere and override each other. I'm just not sure if it's by the standards or a buggy implementation.

Comment: yup, separate the font-styles into different font families works as expected, that means I must embed at least the oblique font style with CSS, I guess this may be a bug of the font system itself.

Answer (score 0):

[The dist css in the Github repo only links the italic version](https://github.com/rubjo/victor-mono/blob/master/dist/index.css) - I've seen issues when `oblique` is referenced in this way, so that may be causing problems. [The demo site's css](https://github.com/rubjo/victor-mono/blob/master/src/styles/globals.scss) declares them separately like Fahim Khan's answer mentions, so that may be what you have to do if you want to reference them separately.

I'm not sure the designer intended for you to be able to use the three styles together like that, or how it would be done - the example code only uses the normal and italic together. IIRC, most editors have a separate bold font setting you can set to a different font - this may be how they're combining them in their editor, by setting that to the italic version.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the font designer's intention, for me it seems the implementation of "font-style: italic" and "font-style: oblique" are broken as they interfere and override each other. Albeit I'm not sure if it's the intended effect of the CSS standards (ie. oblique and italic rules should override each other)?

Comment: [This talks a little bit more about oblique vs italic](https://www.zubair.info/blog/2010/11/05/css-font-style-oblique-vs-italic.html) - it may be that you can't declare a @font-face to be oblique, since the rendering engine generally takes the normal one and slants it itself, or it wasn't intended to have a separate italic and oblique versions being used simultaneously in this manner (they generally aren't), since there is some substituting for italic done when that font style doesn't exist. I really couldn't find any standard/spec that backs up this, though.

Comment: Well, from what I have observed, the oblique rule is valid, however it is simply treated the same as italic, and will override the previous italic rule, and vice versa. So if I declare italic font face first then oblique later for the same font-family, both "font-style: italic" and "font-style: oblique" will show the oblique version. While if I declare italic font-face after a previous oblique rule, both "font-style: italic" and "font-style: oblique" will show the italic version. Seems like a bug to me. And I think there are plenty use cases to use both italic and oblique versions of a font...

Comment: That makes sense. What’s your VSCode config to separate the comments and reversed words like that?